# Throttling HammerJS?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, gestures

My -admittedly shoddy- phone is complaining about "Handling of 'touchmove' input event was delayed for 117 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responive."

I'm trying to do some rotating + scaling. It appears it's Hammer itself that is making Android Chrome choke, but I cannot find what is happening exactly. How do I make Hammer a bit less intensive here?